# How to display bullet points under ~responsive~ horizontal timeline?

Tags: html, css, responsive, breadcrumbs, timeline

I'm trying to display some bullet points under each of the components of this breadcrumb-style timeline. I have gotten the answer to how to put bullets under the timeline while it's full screen but I don't know how to have the points display while the screen is squished or the **screen size is smaller. How would I make the points display under each of the parts of the timeline, being responsive?** If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #4679bd;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#crumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
#crumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
/* bullet points under timeline */
ul.points {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
ul.points li {
  list-style: square!important;
  display: block!important;
  display: list-item!important;
}
/*-----------------------*/
#crumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  background: #8bdbed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 0 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #8bdbed;
  position: absolute;
  right: -90px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul.points {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
ul.points li {
  list-style: square!important;
  display: block!important;
  display: list-item!important;
}
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/*Max width for smaller screen size*/

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="">
      <a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a>
      <ul class="points">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
      <ul class="points">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a>
    </li>

    <li class=""><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here are pictures of what I would like it to look like:

[image]
[image: The bullet points would ideally go in between the white spaces]

Comment: @Paulie_D When the **screen size is 1100px or smaller**, the bullet points would ideally go under each of the steps on the timeline. The little white space between the steps would have the points.

Comment: @Paulie_D see above images

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using col-xs-3.  For larger screens you need to put some tries on it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #4679bd;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#crumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
#crumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
/* bullet points under timeline */
ul.points {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
ul.points li {
  list-style: square!important;
  display: block!important;
  display: list-item!important;
}
/*-----------------------*/
#crumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  background: #8bdbed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 0 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #8bdbed;
  position: absolute;
  right: -90px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul.points {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
ul.points li {
  list-style: square!important;
  display: block!important;
  display: list-item!important;
}
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/*Max width for smaller screen size*/

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}

</style>

<br>

<div id="crumbs">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
      <a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a>
      <!-- <ul class="points">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul> -->
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
      <a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
      <!-- <ul class="points">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul> -->
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0px;margin:0;"><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-xs-3" style="padding:0px;margin:0;"><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```